# Kotlin synchronized inine

Tags: kotlin

Is it known that you cannot synchronize an inlined function in Kotlin? I cannot find any documentation on this.

Imagine you have a class with a synchronized method;

```
/**
 * Allows modifying the value in a synchronized way so that the get() and set() are atomic.
 *
 * Note: anything synchronized cannot be `inline`.
 */
@Synchronized fun safeSet(calculateNewValue: (T) -> T) {
    set(calculateNewValue(get()))
}
```

When this function is `inlined` this test fails, when it is not `inlined` it passes.

```
@Test
fun `safeSet - is synchronized`() {
    val insideSet = AtomicInteger()
    val threadsRun = CountDownLatch(2)
    val t1 = Thread({
        threadsRun.countDown()
        sut.safeSet { currentValue: Int ->
            insideSet.incrementAndGet()
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100000)
            } catch (interrupted: InterruptedException) {
                BoseLog.debug(interrupted)
            }
            currentValue + 1
        }
    })
    t1.start()

    val t2 = Thread({
        threadsRun.countDown()
        sut.safeSet { currentValue: Int ->
            insideSet.incrementAndGet()
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100000)
            } catch (interrupted: InterruptedException) {
                BoseLog.debug(interrupted)
            }
            currentValue + 2
        }
    })
    t2.start()

    threadsRun.await()
    Thread.sleep(100)
    assertEquals(1, insideSet.get())
    t1.interrupt()
    t2.interrupt()
    Thread.sleep(100)
    assertEquals(2, insideSet.get())
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Synchronized` annotation tells the compiler to generate the `ACC_SYNCHRONIZED` flag on the method. Inline functions are not compiled to methods, so the annotation is indeed ignored.

There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27310) in Kotlin for handling this situation better.